# Single php while one three different classes of images

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

i am using a main fours divs first div has class ad1, second and third div has class ad2 and then last div has class ad3...

i want to display 4 images from database
How to do it through while loop, please help, Thanks :) 
here is html code and the php code....

```
<div class="col-md-9 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="ad1">
                <img src="" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="ad2">
                <img src="" alt="">
            </div>
        </div> 

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="ad2">
                <img src="" alt="">
            </div>
        </div> 

        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="ad3">
                <img src="" alt="">
            </div>
        </div> 
</div>
```

php code is

```
<?php
 $query = "SELECT * FROM headerimages limit 4";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($query));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{?>

<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I recommend to use pdo database driver.
In your code the fast fix will be to assign result to array and simply echo it in the view.

```
$result = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$result[]=$row['img'];
}
```

and in view echo it

```
<div class="col-md-9 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="ad1">
                <img src="<?=$result[0]?>" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="ad2">
                <img src="<?=$result[1]?>" alt="">
            </div>
        </div> 

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="ad2">
                <img src="<?=$result[2]?>" alt="">
            </div>
        </div> 

        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="ad3">
                <img src="<?=$result[3]?>" alt="">
            </div>
        </div> 
</div>
```